# Как определять падеж причастия в предложениях?

Tags: падежи, причастия

*Как / по каким критериям* можно определить в предложениях падеж действительных причастий прошедшего времени? Не только в тех, которые я здесь написал, но и в других предложениях, где встречаются эти причастия?

1. "Шумеры были первым народом, изобретшим элементарную систему письма".
2. "На этом сайте вы найдете информацию о солдатах, погибших или пропавших без вести в годы Великой Отечественной войны."

Как определить падеж причастий в этих предложениях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Шумеры были первым народом, изобретшим элементарную систему письма.

*Шумеры были **(кем? чем?) народом, изобретшим**...* -- творительный падеж.

> На этом сайте вы найдете информацию о солдатах, погибших или
>   пропавших...

*На этом сайте вы найдете информацию **(о ком?) о солдатах, погибших** или **пропавших** без вести*... -- предложный падеж.

Answer (score 0):

Падеж причастий узнаётся по падежу определяющего слова. В данном случае — существительного. Всё также, как и у прилагательных.